# Support for multi-tenancy in spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark

Can someone help me understand multi-tenancy aspects of Spark?

I need to share a cluster running Spark. The data and the jobs being executed should be multi-tenant. There are chances that the jobs being executed are from two competitors.

Are there any links / documents or real-life use-cases which can help me understand on these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use this link : https://www.slideshare.net/StampedeCon/apache-hadoop-yarn-multitenancy-capacity-scheduler-preemption-stampedecon-2015

But yes, Sergey is right. Multitenancy is not there yet in YARN. You can use mesos.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't seem possible with YARN until https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-796 is implemented.

You can, however, run Spark with Mesos https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html and then use labels, constraints and/or fake resources so your jobs will be able to run only on specific machines in your cluster.